# mongodb how to get max value from collections

Tags: mongodb, max

I have a mongodb collection like:

```
db.kids.find()
//results
[
    {name:'tom', age:10},
    {name:'alice', age:12},
    ....
]
```

I need a query to get MAX 'age' from this collection
like in SQL: `SELECT MAX(age) FROM kids WHERE 1`

Comment: you can use `db.collection.find().sort({age:-1}).limit(1)`

Answer (score 202):

[As one of comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076382/mongodb-how-to-get-max-value-from-collections/32077240#comment52049875_32076382):

```
db.collection.find().sort({age:-1}).limit(1) // for MAX
db.collection.find().sort({age:+1}).limit(1) // for MIN
```

it's completely usable but i'm not sure about performance

Comment: In case of a large collection, it's better to define an index on `age` field. Then if you use `db.collection.find({}, {age: 1, _id:0}).sort({age:-1}).limit(1)`, you probably would have a very fast [Covered Query](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/query-optimization/#covered-query)

Comment: @AliDehghani Would this method works on mongo shards?

Comment: For anyone searching for something related to the aggregation, You can use this in aggregation if you're using mongoose, as follows: `Model.aggregate([YOUR_QUERY]).sort({age:-1}).limit(1)`

Answer (score 110):

The performance of the suggested answer is fine. According to the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#agg-sort-limit-coalescence):

> ***When a $sort immediately precedes a $limit***, the optimizer can coalesce the $limit into the $sort. This allows **the sort operation
>   to only maintain the top n results** as it progresses, where **n is
>   the specified limit**, and MongoDB only needs to store n items in
>   memory.
>
> Changed in version 4.0.

So in the case of

```
db.collection.find().sort({age:-1}).limit(1)
```

we get only the highest element **WITHOUT** sorting the collection because of the mentioned optimization.

Comment: that documentation link is for aggregation. Are you sure `find( ... ).sort( ... ).limit( ... )` is treated the same way as `aggregate([{$match: ... }, {$sort: ...}, {$limit: ...}])`? is there any place in the mongo docs that they mention this?

Comment: @jmmut https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#limit-results

Answer (score 38):

what about using aggregate framework:

```
db.collection.aggregate({ $group : { _id: null, max: { $max : "$age" }}});
```

Comment: This is not as efficient as the sort.limit. Still, I know deep down everyone feels weird about that sort and limit...

Comment: @AFP_555 Really surprised to know that aggregate is slower than a sort-limit query. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: is aggregate slower than sort-limit query?

Comment: I do the simple test case. Create a collection with 1,000,000 documents {name: "player ", score: x}. 
The .find().sort({score:-1}).limit(1); take more time than .aggregate([{ $group : { _id: null, max: { $max : "$score" }}}])

Comment: @tuananh, this can happen if you don't have an index on "score". In this case sort will have to do O(n log n) operations, while aggregate will only do one scan O(n). With indexed field, sort(...).limit(1) will be very fast constant time O(1) operation.

Answer (score 7):

Folks you can see what the optimizer is doing by running a plan. The generic format of looking into a plan is from the MongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/index.html) . i.e. `Cursor.plan()`. If you really want to dig deeper you can do a `cursor.plan(true)` for more details.

Having said that if you have an index, your `db.col.find().sort({"field":-1}).limit(1)` will read one index entry - even if the index is default ascending and you wanted the max entry and one value from the collection.

In other words the suggestions from @yogesh is correct.

Thanks - Sumit

Answer (score 3):

```
db.collection.findOne().sort({age:-1}) //get Max without need for limit(1)
```

Comment: At least in Mongo 4.2, that syntax will get you a `TypeError: db.collection.findOne(...).sort is not a function`.  collection.findOne() returns the document itself, so calling sort() on it seems unlikely to work.

Answer (score 3):

Below query will get you max age without other fields,

```
db.collection.find({}, {"_id":0, "age":1}).sort({age:-1}).limit(1)
```

Below query will get you max age along with all the collection fields,

```
db.collection.find({}).sort({age:-1}).limit(1)
```

Comment: Can you please explain this part: {"_id":0, "age":1}. I am trying to translate this into a spring @Aggregation.

Comment: This is simple projection in Mongo what fields we want to return from a query. If we query Mongo it will give "_id" by default unless explicitly projected as {"_id":0}, and we needed only age so added ("age": 1}

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Explanation, 
if you have mongo query Response** something like below -
and you want only highest value from **Array->  "Date"**

```
{
  "_id": "57ee5a708e117c754915a2a2",
  "TotalWishs": 3,
  "Events": [
    "57f805c866bf62f12edb8024"
  ],
  "wish": [
    "Cosmic Eldorado  Mountain Bikes, 26-inch (Grey/White)",
    "Asics Men's Gel-Nimbus 18 Black, Snow and Fiery Red Running Shoes - 10 UK/India (45 EU) (11 US)",
    "Suunto Digital Black Dial Unisex Watch - SS018734000"
  ],
  "Date": [
    "2017-02-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    "2017-03-05T00:00:00.000Z"
  ],
  "UserDetails": [
    {
      "createdAt": "2016-09-30T12:28:32.773Z",
      "jeenesFriends": [
        "57edf8a96ad8f6ff453a384a",
        "57ee516c8e117c754915a26b",
        "58a1644b6c91d2af783770b0",
        "57ef4631b97d81824cf54795"
      ],
      "userImage": "user_profile/Male.png",
      "email": "roopak@small-screen.com",
      "fullName": "Roopak Kapoor"
    }
  ],

},
```

***Then you have add

> Latest_Wish_CreatedDate: { $max: "$Date"},

somthing like below-

```
{ 
                $project : { _id: 1,
                             TotalWishs : 1 ,
                              wish:1 ,
                               Events:1, 
                               Wish_CreatedDate:1,
                               Latest_Wish_CreatedDate: { $max: "$Date"},
                            } 
            }
```

**And Final Query Response will be below**

```
{
  "_id": "57ee5a708e117c754915a2a2",
  "TotalWishs": 3,
  "Events": [
    "57f805c866bf62f12edb8024"
  ],
  "wish": [
    "Cosmic Eldorado  Mountain Bikes, 26-inch (Grey/White)",
    "Asics Men's Gel-Nimbus 18 Black, Snow and Fiery Red Running Shoes - 10 UK/India (45 EU) (11 US)",
    "Suunto Digital Black Dial Unisex Watch - SS018734000"
  ],
  "Wish_CreatedDate": [
    "2017-03-05T00:00:00.000Z",
    "2017-02-13T00:00:00.000Z"
  ],
  "UserDetails": [
    {
      "createdAt": "2016-09-30T12:28:32.773Z",
      "jeenesFriends": [
        "57edf8a96ad8f6ff453a384a",
        "57ee516c8e117c754915a26b",
        "58a1644b6c91d2af783770b0",
        "57ef4631b97d81824cf54795"
      ],
      "userImage": "user_profile/Male.png",
      "email": "roopak@small-screen.com",
      "fullName": "Roopak Kapoor"
    }
  ],
  "Latest_Wish_CreatedDate": "2017-03-05T00:00:00.000Z"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

For max value, we can write sql query as

```
select age from table_name order by age desc limit 1
```

same way we can write in mongodb too.

```
db.getCollection('collection_name').find().sort({"age" : -1}).limit(1); //max age
db.getCollection('collection_name').find().sort({"age" : 1}).limit(1); //min age
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this through aggregate pipeline.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$sort:{age:-1}}, {$limit:1}])
```

Comment: This has a terrible perfomance. Getting the highest value always costs `O(n)` without indicies. This has a performance of `O(n log(n))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
db.collection.findOne({}, null, {sort: {age: -1}})
```

Will return you one doc with max age