# How can I get max value in nested documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection(named **menucategories**) in MongoDB 3.2.11:

```
{
    "_id" : ...
    "menus" : [
        {
            "code":0
        },
        {
            "code":1
        },
        {
            "code":2
        },
        {
            "code":3
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ...
    "menus" : [
        {
            "code":4
        },
        {
            "code":5
        },
        {
            "code":6
        },
        {
            "code":7
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ...
    "menus" : [
        {
            "code":8
        },
        {
            "code":9
        },
        {
            "code":10
        },
        {
            "code":11
        }
    ]
}
```

Every **menucategory** has array named **menus**. And every menu(element of the array) has **code**. The '**code**' of menus is unique in every **menu**. I wanna get the maximum value of menu's code(in this case, **11**). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongodb how to get max value from collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076382/mongodb-how-to-get-max-value-from-collections)

Comment: @SmitaAhinave this is not a valid duplicate. Op specifically  mentioned that they are on MongoDB 3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find maximum value of code from all menus code then probable query will be as follows:

```
db.menucategories.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$menus' },
  { $group: { _id: null, max: { $max: '$menus.code' } } },
  { $project: { max: 1, _id:0 } }
])
```

Click below links for more information regarding different operators:

[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

Comment: Your comment on @ShaishabRoy's now deleted answer is wrong. You don't  always need to put your pipeline in an array. Also note that OP is using MongoDB 3.2 which means that your answer here is only *factually* correct.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the `$unwind` aggregation pipeline operator here because starting from MongoDB 3.2, some [accumulator expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2/#agg-accumulator-availability) are available in the `$project` stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$project": {"maxPerDoc": {"$max": "$menus.code"}}}, 
    {"$group": {"_id": null, "maxValue": {"$max": "$maxPerDoc"}}}
])
```

Responding a previous now deleted comment, you don't need to put your pipeline in an array so the following query will work as well.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    {"$project": {"maxPerDoc": {"$max": "$menus.code"}}}, 
    {"$group": {"_id": null, "maxValue": {"$max": "$maxPerDoc"}}}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate({ $group : { _id: 1, max: { $max: {$max : "$menus.code"}}}});
```

No need of any unwind, if you need find only maximum value.

Comment: let me know what is the mistake in this for Down voting.?

Comment: This is the fastest solution from all. Tested it myself and saved ~30% runtime! +1 from me!