# How can I aggregate nested documents?

Tags: mongodb, nested, aggregation-framework

I have a collection :

```
{
    _id : xxx,
    children : [
        {
            childrenOfChildren : [
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            childrenOfChildren : [
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            childrenOfChildren : [
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},

{
    _id : xxx,
    children : [
        {
            childrenOfChildren : [
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            childrenOfChildren : [
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            childrenOfChildren : [
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},

{
    _id : xxx,
    children : [
        {
            childrenOfChildren : [
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            childrenOfChildren : [
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            childrenOfChildren : [
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},

{
    _id : xxx,
    children : [
        {
            childrenOfChildren : [
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            childrenOfChildren : [
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            childrenOfChildren : [
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                },
                {
                    price : xxx
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Every entry has an array named **children**. And Every entry in children has an array named **childrenOfChildren**. And every entry in childrenOfChildren has an attribute named **price**. I wanna get maximum value of price in this overall collection. How can I achieve this? Please help me!

Comment: can try using `aggregate` query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get max value in nested documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327672/how-can-i-get-max-value-in-nested-documents)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this using $unwind and $group.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $unwind:"$children"
   },
   {
      $unwind:"$children.childrenOfChildren"
   },
   {
      $group:{
         _id:null,
         maxPrice:{
            $max:"$children.childrenOfChildren.price"
         }
      }
   }
])
```

output:

```
{ "_id" : null, "maxPrice" : 110 }
```

try it online: [mongoplayground.net/p/sBTclni0YSw](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sBTclni0YSw)

Answer (score 1):

you can get maximum price from overall collection by using `aggregate` query with `$unwind` and `$group`.

can try this query:

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').aggregate([
 {$unwind: "$children"},
 {$unwind: "$children.childrenOfChildren"},
 {$group:{_id: null, price:{$max: "$children.childrenOfChildren.price"}}}
])
```