# How to find max sum after $group sorting

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following query:

```
db.pmusers.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: '$preferableUsersIds'
    },
    {
        $group:{_id: '$preferableUsersIds', number:{$sum: 1}}
    },
    {
        $sort:{number:-1}
    },
    {
        $limit:1
    }
])
```

I understand that it is not the optimal solution because I sort all rntries instead of find only one.

Does mongoDb support to rewrite it in more efficient way?

### P.S.

I know aboout [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) but don't see how it can help me.

---

this one works at least not faster:

```
db.pmusers.aggregate([
      {
          $unwind: '$preferableUsersIds'
      },
      {
          $sortByCount: "$preferableUsersIds"
      },
      {
          $limit:1
      }
  ])
```

Comment: Could you perhaps post some sample data, please?

Answer (score 0):

See the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41503983/1881027)

MongoDB coalesces the sort and limit in an aggregation to optimise the query. You can also add an index if you're doing this a lot to make sure it's a covered query.

Text from linked answer:

> According to the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#agg-sort-limit-coalescence):
>
> When a $sort immediately precedes a $limit, the optimizer can coalesce
>   the $limit into the $sort. This allows the sort operation to only
>   maintain the top n results as it progresses, where n is the specified
>   limit, and MongoDB only needs to store n items in memory.

Comment: which index can help at the moment ?

Comment: In the case of this query specifically, no index will help. Unfortunately anything after a mutation like $unwind is no longer working with your collection directly, but a modified result set, so the index can't be used.

I would suggest looking into doing a $match before the $unwind and setting up an index based on that match. Of course, this depends on your use case, as you haven't really provided much context.