# MongoDB with Java: Finding the document with max value

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a rudimentary at best understanding of MongoDB and aggregation. I have not been able to find a clear example of how one might compare multiple documents which match a criteria and return 1 document with the maximum value in a specific attribute.

Say we have the following documents in a collection:

```
{ name: "a" , value: 2 }
{ name: "a" , value: 4 }
{ name: "a" , value: 6 }
{ name: "b" , value: 2 }
{ name: "b" , value: 8 }
```

How would I filter by `name` (`eq("name","a")`) and then return the document with the highest `value`?

Comment: Maybe there is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076382/mongodb-how-to-get-max-value-from-collections). 
```db.collection.find({name: "a"}).sort({value:-1}).limit(1)```

Comment: @BogdanOros That's my current method of doing it, looking for something a little more elegant/efficient. Thank you anyway, should've mentioned.

Comment: You may use some aggregation features with ```$max```, but the sort+limit solution is more efficient.

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light in addition, to make the `sort().limit()` efficient, you would also need an index on the `value` field.

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```
 db.collection.aggregate(
 [
   {
     $group: {
       _id: "$name",
       values: {$addToSet: "$value"}
     }
   },
   {
     $project:{
     _id: 0, name: "$_id", value: {$max: "$values"}
     }
   }
])
```