# Return highest number in grouped data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have grouped some data by some conditions and get the expected result. However, I would like to only return the item with the **highest number** in each `pool`. If I only would like to have the highest one I could add `.sort({ correctBets: -1 }).limit(1)` to the end,  but now I need one in each pool. And if two or more correctBets is the same in one pool I would like to return all those items. How would I do this?

```
const coupon = await CouponModel.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        eventId: { $in: eventIds },
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          userId: '$userId',
          pool: '$pool',
        },
        correctBets: {
          $sum: '$correctBets',
        },
      },
    },
  ])
```

This is the data I get returned from the aggregate.

```
[ 
  { _id: { userId: '5df344a1372f345308dac12a', pool: 'foo' },
    correctBets: 9 },
  { _id: { userId: '5dfb2db245011a390fec4f7d', pool: 'bar' },
    correctBets: 6 },
  { _id: { userId: '5df344a1372f345308dac12a', pool: 'bar' },
    correctBets: 5 },
  { _id: { userId: '5dfb2db245011a390fec4f7d', pool: 'foo' },
    correctBets: 11 } 
]
```

My expected result should look like this

```
[
  { _id: { userId: '5dfb2db245011a390fec4f7d', pool: 'foo' },
    correctBets: 11 },
  { _id: { userId: '5dfb2db245011a390fec4f7d', pool: 'bar' },
    correctBets: 6 }
]
```

Edit: the proposed duplicate question dont handle max values for each 'key' as in my case is two pools. Foo and bar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongodb how to get max value from collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076382/mongodb-how-to-get-max-value-from-collections)

Comment: Unfortunately not as it would only return the highest of one pool. I need the highest in booth pools. The answer below did work. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add extra stages. We need to calculate max `correctBets` for each `pool` field and store documents into temporal `data` field. Then we flatten `data` and check if any document stored inside data has the same `correctBets` with max value.

```
{
    $group: {
      _id: {
        pool: "$_id.pool"
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      },
      correctBets: {
        $max: "$correctBets"
      }
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$data"
},
{
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          "$correctBets",
          "$data.correctBets"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
{
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$data"
    }
}
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-7L_iutUgtb)

Comment: Thanks! However, if two userIds in the same pool has the same amount of correctBets, the result includes only one of them. I would like to have both if they tie.

Comment: @GameAtrix check it again please

Comment: It returns all of them now in the playground?

Comment: Yes, now it works as intended. Thank you very much!